# Подобрать ОС для SQL Server

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, windows-server

Уважаемые коллеги помогите с не легким выбором. Мы у нас в регионе хотим создать единую базу данных для сбора и анализа статистических данных по образовательным организациям, а именно по школа. **Школ в регионе всего 450**, общее **количество детей 220 000**. Сервер мы приобрели. Он у нас в виде шасси на котором четыре таких блэйд-сервера:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

СУБД – **SQL Server** и будет установлен **на одном таком блэйд-сервере** (т.е. без каких либо виртуальных делений). Правда мы еще не определились какой редакцией она будет. Больше склоняюсь как минимум должна быть SQL Server **Standard**.

Самый трудный выбор и о чем я хочу спросить, какая операционная система нам нужна – на чем так сказать «крутить» SQL Server? Windows Server или подойдет обычная клиентская ОС?

Нужно чтобы выдерживалось подключения **одновременно 500 клиентов к SQL Server** для вноса статистики. Вычислений не будут. Если и будут, то одновременно у 40-50 клиентов с перебором **около 1000 записей**.

Трудность в том, что в бюджете сейчас денег нет. Мы за сервер отдали всего 200 000 р. А по моим подсчетам, чтобы приобрести только SQL Server на такой блэйд-сервер выходит в пределах **600 000 рублей**. Нужен оптимальный вариант. Но если встанет вопрос: «брать самый лучший или вообще не брать». То проект надо отложить до финансирования.

И еще раз вопрос: **Нужен ли мне Windows Server для моей базы?** И если да, то конкретно какие преимущества он несет? И какой редакции Windows Server приобретать?

Если там «замахиваться» на Windows Server **Datacenter**, то он тоже в «копеечку» выйдет.

Comment: @HermannZheboldov, но SQL Server устанавливается только на Windows? Разве не так? Или вы о другом?

Comment: А зачем использовать SQL Server? Это критично?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно лучше все и сразу, но если денег нет то есть следующие варианты:

1. Установить SQL Server Standard на win 7 или 8 для экономии,
   потом когда появятся - мигрировать. Базу перенести - дело пары часов .
2. Установить на Windows Server SQL Server Express бесплатный -  потом когда 
   бюджет появится - мигрировать на другую редакцию. Переезд несложный будет.

Вариант 2 имхо хуже из-за сильных ограничений на производительность.

Comment: у express'а ограничение по размеру БД всего в 4 гб - так что он подходит только для тренировок

Comment: не 4гб, а 10гб.

Comment: @Ivan, тогда у меня вопрос: SQL Server редакции Expres будет использовать все 8 ядер моего сервера? На сколько я понял Express задействует не всю мощность. Вы именно это имеете ввиду когда говорите, что второй вариант хуже?

Comment: не всю да.  Юзает один cpu  и всего 1 гиг озу + размер базы 10гб (но баз может быть много).  
Я бы рекомендовал все же первый вариант.  ОС таки куда меньшее влияние будет оказывать чем версия самого сервера!!

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте обратится в Microsoft, у них действует специальная программа для школ:
[Специальные условия лицензирования ПО для учреждений начального и среднего образования на 2015 год](http://www.microsoft.com/rus/education/deal.aspx)

> В связи с окончанием 31 декабря 2014 года срока действия действующих Соглашений по программе School Agreement («Первая помощь») на право использования программного обеспечения Microsoft учреждениями системы начального и среднего образования РФ, а также органами управления образования регионального и муниципального уровня, Microsoft объявляет о новых специальных условиях на период с 1 января 2015 по 31 декабря 2015 года.

Специальное предложение базируется на программе School Agreement, которая обеспечивает лицензирование всего парка ПК образовательного учреждения. В рамках специального предложения предлагается базовый пакет, а также набор продуктов, лицензии на которые могут быть приобретены дополнительно. По правилам программы School Agreement минимальный объем заказываемых лицензий составляет 50 баллов, что соответствует заказу 13 базовых пакетов. Базовый пакет должен быть приобретен на каждый ПК учреждения.

Следует иметь в виду, что в рамках данной программы лицензирования не предоставляется возможность приобретения полной версии операционной системы Windows. Доступна только Upgrade-версия Windows, для использования которой необходимо наличие базовой лицензии: OEM-версии или Get Genuine Windows® Agreement for Academic (GGWA-A).

Воспользоваться настоящим специальным предложением могут следующие виды образовательных учреждений:

- Общеобразовательные учреждения;
- Органы управления образованием всех уровней (федеральный,
  региональный, муниципальный);
- Учреждения дошкольного образования;
- Учреждения начального и среднего профессионального образования;
- Учреждения дополнительного образования для детей;
- Учреждения дополнительного образования для учителей.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но это моя вина - я не договорил. Тут имеется ввиду, что школы будут заполнять базу через отдельно созданное ПО. ПО будет десктопное и еще веб-портал. Т.е. тут не идут в ход программы на подобии SSMS.

Comment: 1.SQL Server надо ставить на серверную ОС. 2. Версия SQL server Standard поддерживает до 64Gb памяти - учитывайте это.

Comment: У меня сейчас SQL Server стоит на клиентской Windows 8.1 и работает нормально. Или при одновременном подключении нескольких пользователей клиентская ОС дает сбой?

Comment: конечно вы можете использовать даже Express версию SQL Server на десктопной ОС в качестве временного решения. Но это накладывает много ограничений на такое решение.

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос в том, что подразумевается под "одновременно"? 40-50 человек будут вносить данные действительно одновременно - осуществлять запись пачки данных в одну и ту же секунду? Это явно завышенная оценка. Количество пользователей и детей ничего не говорит о предполагаемой нагрузке. Нужно оценивать количество одновременно выполняемых запросов.

Например "40-50 клиентов с перебором около 1000 записей" - 1000 записей SQL Server перебирает за пару десятков миллисекунд (в худшем случае). Чтобы получить 40 одновременных выборок, вам нужна нагрузка в 4000 запросов в секунду. Это 240 000 в минуту. Т.е. для этого вам придется усадить за комп всех учеников ваших школ, и заставить каждого раз в минуту нажимать кнопку "обновить".

Как вы собираетесь организовать доступ из разных школ? Они будут подключаться напрямую к SQL Server (судя по предполагаемым 500 соединений)? Если да - то это очень плохая идея. SQL Server надо прятать за Web-сервисом. Иначе малолетний *хакер* из одной из 500 школ затрет вам половину базы, и вы даже не сможете найти кто это сделал :) Если прямого подключения не планируется - то откуда предполагаемое требование в 500 соединений?

Хостить SQL Server на своем железе дорого. Хостить его с хоть каким-то дублированием и отказоустойчивостью - **ОЧЕНЬ ДОРОГО**.

Если у вас нет сверхстрогих требований к скорости работы, и 50 - это количество пользователей, а не одновременно выполняемых операций - лучше использовать [SQL Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/).

[Цены там](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) от 1500 руб в месяц за Standard S1 - должно хватить для не слишком нагруженного приложения. Надежность 99.95% и возможность восстановления в любую точку на две недели назад.

Comment: касаемо доступа к базе: Планирую сделать клиентское приложение, которое будет работать напрямую с базой (без сервера приложений) с помощью LINQ-запросов.

Comment: Клиентское приложение - не слишком удачный вариант. Разделить доступ на уровне строк в SQL Server можно, но достаточно сложно (как и в любой другой базе данных). Делая прямой доступ из клиентского приложения вы практически предоставляете полный доступ к базе неизвестным лицам. Рассмотрите вариант с вебсервисом, или просто с сайтом.

Comment: разве тот же сайт не является тем же (веб) приложением, которое также обращается напрямую к SQL Server?

Comment: да, но для сайта разным людям вы можете выдать разные пароли. и отзывать их по необходимости отзывать их. вы можете сделать принудительные фильтры на данные, так, чтобы человек из одной школы не видел и не мог редактировать данные другой. и сайт убирает требование в 500 открытых соединений - т.к. сайту достаточно столько открытых соединений, сколько запросов выполняется через него в данный момент (скорее всего до 10 с вашим количеством пользователей). а еще сайт не надо обновлять на 500 машинах при выходе новой версии :)

Comment: Единственный толковый ответ, не попавший в ловушку XY.